# Rails whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm trying to set up `whenever` gem, but I can't. `schedule.rb` file:

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron-whenever.log"

every '1 * * * *' do
  command "#{path}/sh_files/db_backup.sh"
end
```

Setting up:

```
 ~# whenever --update-crontab everything
 [write] crontab file updated
 ~# crontab -l

 # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: everything
  1 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/some/path/to/files/db_backup.sh >> /some/path/to/files/cron-whenever.log 2>&1'
 # End Whenever generated tasks for: everything
```

And after starting rails server and waiting... nothing happens. No `logs` update, do `db_backup.sh` update. Nothing... And I checked manually `/some/path/to/files/db_backup.sh` command, it works...

Comment: check the log here `tail -f  /var/log/syslog` on linux

Comment: check cron status. `service cron status`

Comment: This appears to be a `cron` problem, check [reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Comment: @Marwen Thanks! It works now. It was PATH problem and now its fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be **schedule.rb** instead of **scheduler.rb** according to the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: And it is, just mistyped while I was writing my question here. Its generated by `$ wheneverize .` command and I didn't change path or file name. Still, doesn't work.